# Custom Split or Transform values in Tableau column

Tags: tableau-api, transformation

I have a Location column within Tableau that contains data that look like this:

```
GVA - Equi GV2  Geneva
GVA - Equi GV2  Geneva
GVA - Equi GV2  Geneva
AMS - Equi2 AM1 Amsterdam
AMS - Equi2 AM1 Amsterdam
```

Is there a way to remove the prefix to just show the location?

Desired output:

```
Geneva
Geneva
Geneva
Amsterdam
Amsterdam
```

I have tried going into Tableau on the main page and performing a custom split. However, when doing this, I do not see any changes:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about defining your custom Split as the **Last** 1 column (instead of the First)?

Of course if a location has a space in the name, you'll only see the last word.

You can also use the REGEXP_EXTRACT() function to specify a more sophisticated pattern.

Comment: Good suggestion. I will try this